# Call Recording Twilio Proxy API PHP

Tags: php, twilio, call, call-recording

i have been trying to record call using twilio proxy api. But i am having a weird issue i got a couple of twilio number but on one number call is being recorded perfectly but on others it just doesnt record call here is my code that was placed in the callback url

```
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
                $inbound_id=$_REQUEST['inboundParticipantSid'];
$recording = $twilio->calls($_REQUEST['inboundResourceSid'])->recordings->create(['recordingStatusCallback'=>
"https://tvmount.services/wbadmin2/record.php?inbound_id=".$inbound_id]);
```

i tried debugging it and the problem is that on my other twilio numbers it just dont redirect to the record.php .

Comment: Is the API request successful for the numbers where this isn't working, or does it throw an error? You might not be getting the status callback webhook, but do you see the recording in the Twilio console at all?

Comment: No twilio just dont excecute call recording it also does not record calls. where is with one specific number it does record calls and redirects to record.php

Comment: If it works for one number, but not for another, and the code is the same, then this sounds like you need to contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).